# Tell UIViewController about something that happened in a subview

Tags: ios, uiview, uiviewcontroller

I have a `UIViewController` with a `UIView` as a subview.  I'd like the `UIViewController` to be notified of (or listen for) certain actions in the `UIView`. **What's the standard way of doing this?**

Comment: What kind of actions?  A button press?  A property has its value change?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to have an action handler:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // ......
    UIButton *myButton = [[UIButton alloc] init]; // or initWithSOMETHING
    [myButton addTarget:self action:@selector(someMethod:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [self.view addSubview:myButton];
    [myButton release];
    // ......
}

- (void)someMethod:(id)sender {
    if (![sender isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]]) return;
    // Do something about the action here...
}
```

For more info, see the [`UIControl` Documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIControl_Class/Reference/Reference.html):

> Preparing and Sending Action Messages
>
> ```
> – sendAction:to:forEvent:
> – sendActionsForControlEvents:
> – addTarget:action:forControlEvents:
> – removeTarget:action:forControlEvents:
> – actionsForTarget:forControlEvent:
> – allTargets
> – allControlEvents
> ```

---

Or, if your talking about a view controller calling a parent view controller, you could use the `presentingViewController` property of a [`UIViewController`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html) to access the "parent" view controller:

```
UIViewController *parentVC = [self presentingViewController];
[parentVC setSomething:self.withSomething];
```

> **`presentingViewController`** - The view controller that presented this view controller. (read-only)
>
> `@property(nonatomic, readonly) UIViewController
>   *presentingViewController`
>
> **Discussion**
>   The default implementation of this property walks up the view
>   hierarchy, starting from this view controller. The first view
>   controller it finds that received the
>   `presentViewController:animated:completion:` method, or that has its
>   `definesPresentationContext` property set to `YES` is returned as the
>   value of the property. It keeps walking up the hierarchy until it
>   finds a value to return or it gets to the root view controller.

---

Or the `superview` property of a [`UIView`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html):

```
[self.view.superview doSomething];
```

> **`superview`** - The receiver’s superview, or nil if it has none. (read-only)
>   `@property(nonatomic, readonly) UIView *superview`

Answer (score 2):

Based on your answer to the comment above, that this is a button press, the "standard" way would be to use the mechanisms in UIControl.  So, programmatically, if you do

```
[myButton addTarget:myViewController action:@selector(buttonPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

Pressing "myButton" will cause the "buttonPressed:" method to be executed on myViewController.  You can also use Interface Builder to make the connections.

This code could be put in a number of different places (in the UIView, in the UIViewController) and, as a result, the exact name of the variables would change, but, for handling a button pressed, this is probably the easiest way.